# MongoDB - look up vs write - what is better in performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im new with mongo db and wonder: What is faster look up or write:

- write : always replacing/storing a token that could potentially change

  or
- storing token in frontend in asyncStorage and then looking it up in db and comparing, only storing when changed?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for the `findOneAndUpdate()` method perhaps?

Comment: no im not looking for any method. I only want to know what is faster (my question)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The two options you mention are to either 1) make one write call to the database every time or 2) make a read call to the database every time with an additional write sometimes. I'm suggesting that using `findOneAndUpdate()` will work for both cases. In each it'll only require a single call to the database and it will avoid writing (and just do a read) if the data already exists as expected. Seems to be the optimal approach